# Unable to get information from <div> Node spider with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to download the lat/long locations of CCTV locations from the City of Baltimore website (project on the surveillance state) but not getting the console to log anything.

Here's the site:

[image]

and my code is:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


let URL = 'https://data.baltimorecity.gov/Public-Safety/CCTV-Locations/hdyb-27ak/data'
let cameras = [];

request(URL, function(err, res, body) {
  if(!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    let $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('div.blist-t1-c140113793').each(function() {
      let camera = $(this);
      let location = camera.text();
      console.log(location);
      cameras.push(location);
    });
    console.log(cameras);
  }
});
```

I've tried setting the  to `blist-t1-c140113793` and `blist-td blist-t1-c140113793` but neither has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because data for those divs are loaded asynchronously, after the page was rendered. JavaScript is not executed by Cherrio, or any other such library. You'll need either to analyze network traffic and understand which HTTP call loads this data, or use something like Selenium, that actually executes JavaScript inside the browser.